# REST API design and multi-resource using web app view

Tags: api, rest, web-applications

For the webapp that I'm working on, I'm writing a RESTful API which is planned to be used by mobile version of this project as well, hence trying to apply best practices.

I know that each different type resource collection has it's own URI points. For instance I have two two different resources and their URIs:

```
Products: https://api.myproject.com/products/
Users: https://api.myproject.com/users/
```

Here is my question: 
The main page of my webapp displays top 40 products and most popular 10 users. What is the best practice to use in such cases for client to connect via Ajax to fetch these datas? Should a single API point to deliver both Product or User or should client connect to two different API points to fetch Products and Users. The reason is I'm questioning this is because it's a best practice to minimize the number of HTTP requests in webapps is the best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your design should depend on your requirements for this ReSTful service.

If performance is a priority, then you should try to have a single API contact. However, the performance gains from such a design decision are minimal and performance would rather depend on backend implementation for these queries.

However, if modifiability (the ease of programming and implementation) is more important to you, then try to have 2 separate API points wherein you have the flexibility to choose the number of users, products or any entity for each unique implementation throughout your app. You will save a lot of time during the implementation by using this design rather than trying to increase performance marginally.